# Adding RealmObjectChangeListener to a RealmObject downloaded asynchronously

Tags: java, android, realm

Suppose an asynchronous API call returns Member Data which is a RealmObject and Member is saved to realm.

```
public class Member extends RealmObject { 
    String name;
}
```

Now I want to add RealmObjectChangeListener to a Member Object (say, member) so that we can update UI when the data is available. But, to begin with, Member table was empty and member is null as the API call, to fetch member data, is asynchronous. Adding RealmObjectChangeListener to member will result in NullPointerException. How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are listening for all members, then it's easy: keep field reference to the members (easy in a RecyclerView's ViewHolder) and add the RealmObjectChangeListener to the Member obtained from `results.get()`, bound to the ViewHolder.

```
void bind(Member member) {
    if(this.member != null) {
        this.member.removeAllChangeListeners();
    }
    this.member = member;
    this.member.addChangeListener(...);
```

---

Assuming you are waiting for a specific `member` with a specific `name`, and you care only about that member:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private RealmResults<Member> objectResults;
private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Member>> objectTracker = (results) -> {
    if(member != null && member.isValid()) {
        return;
    }
    if(realm.isInTransaction()) {
        handler.post(() -> {
            setupMember(results);
        });
    } else {
        setupMember(results);
    }
};

private void setupMember(RealmResults<Member> members) {
    if(member != null && member.isValid()) {
        member.removeAllChangeListeners();
    }
    member = members.first(null);
    if(member != null) {
        member.addChangeListener((member, fieldChangeSet) -> {
            // do whatever
        }); 
    }
}

private Member member;

private Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    objectResults = realm.where(Member.class).equalTo("name", name).findAllAsync();
    objectResults.addChangeListener(objectTracker);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(member != null) {
        member.removeAllChangeListeners();
    }
    objectResults.removeAllChangeListeners();
    realm.close();
}
```

---

EDIT: if you don't need field-level changes:

```
private RealmResults<Member> objectResults;
private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Member>> objectTracker = (results) -> {
    setupMember(results);
};

private void setupMember(RealmResults<Member> members) {
    Member member = members.first(null);
    if(member != null) {
        updateViews(member); // update views with member
    } else {
        // member doesn't exist or was deleted
    }
}

private Realm realm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    objectResults = realm.where(Member.class).equalTo("name", name).findAllAsync();
    objectResults.addChangeListener(objectTracker);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    objectResults.removeAllChangeListeners();
    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @EpicPandaForce. Coming from an expert, the answer gotta be great! Kudos!

Comment: Thanks for explanation @EpicPandaForce. Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I think second approach suits my case but just a reaffirmation will be helpful. I have HomeActivity where I attach a Dashboard fragment that displays member's point balance and a card UI depending on whether a member card is added. The async call is made in HomeActivity's onResume(). And in onResponse of the async call, I do the realm write. There is only one Member, the one that's logging in. I will clear him on logoff.

Comment: If you don't need fine-grained field-level change listener (so just knowing that the member was updated is enough), then you can ditch the RealmObjectChangeListener and use the RealmChangeListener on the RealmResults instead. Then, the `Member member = results.first(null)` pretty much gives you everything you need, as you can update the views based on that. That ought to simplify this code I wrote up above. You can also make `name` a `@PrimaryKey` just to make sure it behaves as we expect.

Comment: That makes sense Gabor. Putting changeListener on RealmResults as they are never null from my realm-swift understanding. Thanks for timely reply.